# How to add a free information layer in the [top|bottom] toolbar?

Tags: jqgrid

I hope you can help me. I can't find any information about my topic neither in the jqGrid documentation, nor in stackoverflow.
I would like to add a free information layer as shown in the "How it works" section in the jqGrid Documentation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toolbar option of the grid. For example `toolbar: [true, "top"]` add empty div at the top of the grid. The option `toolbar: [true, "both"]` will add top and bottom divs. You can add any custom HTML information in the divs. You can access the dives by ids. See documentation for details. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OneFieldSearching2.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717875/315935) provide an example of usage the top toolbar.